# Andrew Ng's ML course (in python) - Applying gradient descent with multiple variables, confused about intuition

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to create the equation for gradient descent with multiple variables.
Picture of equation:
[https://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/04_Linear_Regression_with_multiple_variables_files/Image%20[3].png](https://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/04_Linear_Regression_with_multiple_variables_files/Image%20%5B3%5D.png)

The final solution is:

```
theta = theta - alpha *((np.dot((np.dot(X,theta)-y), X))*(1/m)).
```

I made an error by adding an extra "np.sum":

```
theta = theta - alpha *((`np.sum`(((np.dot((np.dot(X,theta)-y), X))*(1/m))))*(1/m))
```

I am confused about why the solution does not require an `np.sum` or when exactly does the summation occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.dot` includes the summation of multiplied elements.

```
dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
```

check the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assume X matrix shape is (100, 3) then theta shape is (3, 1) and y is (100,1).
What you wrote:

```
theta = theta - alpha *((np.dot((np.dot(X,theta)-y), X))*(1/m)).
```

This implementation is not mathematically correct, because:
you have mistake in section:
((np.dot((np.dot(X,theta)-y), X))

because, (np.dot(X,theta)-y) shape is 100 * 1 and X shape is 100 * 3 then in terms of the properties of the matrices, We can't multiply these two matrices. Because the first matrix column must be equal to the second matrix row.
please check [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/vectorization-implementation-in-machine-learning-ca652920c55d) and also [this](https://github.com/mohammadkarami95/machine_learning/blob/master/gradient_descent/Multivariate_GD(full%20batch).ipynb).
Also, because you look at the dataset matrixically, then you do'nt need np.sum !!

```
h_x= np.dot(X, theta)
error= h_x - y
theta= theta - (learning_rate * (1/m) * np.dot(X.T, error))
```

Comment: very insightful! Thank you for the links